# BeginForm is not a member of 'Html' and Encode is not a member of HTML

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, view

I'm working on this big project in MVC ASP.NET w\ VB.NET
One of my views is getting me headaches since a few and i'm not sure what's up.
I've used the Begin.Form and Html.Encode methods alot in my other views and i never had any problems. Now this new Create.aspx view for one of my object called Automation is giving me multiple build errors such as those cited in the title plus

> Error 184 'Context' is not a member of
> 'ASP.views_automatisation_create_aspx'.
>
> BeginForm is not a member of 'Html'
>
> Encode is not a member of HTML

My header is as follow (just like all of my other working views headers) :

> <%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(Of XXXXX_XXXXX.Automatisation)" %>

Can anyone help me out ?

Thanks everyone for reading.

Answer (score 2):

Check whether you have renamed your Model.

If you are using strongly typed-view then these kind of error is there.

Note:- Even though, you have added correct namespaces in your program, and most of the errors not specifically gives you the exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

Does it work if you manually import the namespace (below @page):

<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" %>

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have deleted a `<%` somewhere by mistake in your .aspx file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to schlep the little web.config that was in your views folder around? And did you remove any of the `<add />` elements in the  `<pages><namespaces>` bits of your web.config?